# NSIS Simple Service Plugin : cannot call SimpleSC::StartService

Tags: nsis

I want to create a new service in Windows 7 after the user installs my EXE generated with NSIS. I have tried this code `SimpleSC::StartService "TestService" '' 15` and this code 
 `SimpleSC::InstallService "MyService" "My Service Display Name" "16" "2" "E:\utilisateur\xxx.exe" "" "" ""` but neither are working; it displays **Plugin not found, cannot call SimpleSC::StartService**

Comment: This error message was changed in NSIS 3 to make it clearer that the compiler cannot find the plug-in but I guess it did not help?

Comment: thanks for your respone

Comment: Not sure if this was your case, but I was using the ANSI version of the plugin, instead of the Unicode one

Answer (score 9):

You need to [download](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin) the SimpleSC plug-in and extract the .dll into the correct NSIS plug-in folder, typically `c:\Program Files\NSIS\Plugins\x86-ansi` for a NSIS 3 ANSI installer.

Comment: Sorry, why at the ``x86-ansi`` directory?

Comment: @ikreb that is where ansi plugins go in NSIS v3